# Passing an object to a function taking a reference, an interview test

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing

I had an interesting (or stupid) interview question. Well, I know that the code below will not compile, but I could not give any answer on how to modify class C to make the code compile. I was told that answers like `Test(C(1));` or `void Test(C c)` were unacceptable. Can you help me?

Here's the question:

**Q11. Will the following code compile? If not, make any changes you want to class C ONLY in order for the code to compile.**

```
class C
{
public:
    C(int i) {}
    ~C() {}
};

void Test(C &c)
{
}

int main(int, char*)
{
    Test(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what they actually asked you.  Either you misunderstood the question, or posted the question here wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code will not compile.

There is no way to make it compile changing only class `C` first because the signature for `main` is wrong (char* is *never* the type of the second argument).

But even if the signature of `main` were correct `Test(1);` wants to implicitly create a temporary object of `C` and pass that into `Test`. However, you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference, and I can't see any way to change only class `C` to create an implicit temporary that can bind to the parameter to `Test`.

EDIT: The closest I've come is putting `friend void Test(int i) { }` into `C`. This compile with Sun's CC compiler but fails to compile with g++ 4.4, 4.5, or 4.8 from ideone. EDIT2: It appears from 11.4/5 that g++ is correct here: The function is introduced into the scope of the class, not the enclosing scope.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think it is a typo which suggests the question has been copied incorrectly.

Comment: @Mike Seymour Does my final paragraph not address the situation where the OP mis-copied the signature of `main` and it was actually valid?

Comment: @MarkB: Sorry, I was a bit quick to comment; the last paragraph wasn't there at that point (or if it was, I somehow didn't notice it).

Comment: Thank you @Mark B and thank you all! Yes, I copied it incorrectly, it should have been `int main(int, char*[])`, thank you. I think that's it, I should have insisted that there is no other way to do it! And thank you, @Drek, your answer does answer this question, but I cant seriously think that this is what the interviewer wanted.

Answer (score 6):

This task is not possible to answer because the problem does not lie within the class `C`, but in `Test` wanting a non-const reference to `C`.

When calling `Test(1)`, the compile will look at the signature of `Test`, take note that `C` is implicitly constructable from `int` (because it is not `explicit`), but `C(1)` is still an rvalue, and `Test` requires an lvalue.

It would be possible to fix this by either changing the signature of `Test`:

```
void Test(C const & c) {} // or
void Test(C c) {}         // or, since C++11
void Test(C && c) {}
```

or call it with an lvalue in `main` instead:

```
C c(1); // or C c = 1; if you desperately want to keep the implicit conversion
Test(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about http://ideone.com/pnZwh6
It's a hack but it lets the code compile.

```
class C
{
public:
    C(int i) {}
    ~C() {}

#define C const C
};

void Test(C &c)
{
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    Test(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you gave me this task at an interview and not accept this as a solution I'd say no before you do.